# C#: No such host is known exception when trying to resolve DNS query

Tags: c#, .net, dns, ipv4

I am trying to resolve an Ip address in Windows 7.
The DNS server im trying to reach is IPV4 only - therefore I needed to disable IPV6 in the network card and in the registry.

I am trying to use DNS.BeginGetHostEntry(hostname) because I need the ip.
when it reaches DNS.EndGetHostEntry it throws the above exception.
Weird thing is - I can see the Ip address I need in Wireshark as a response from the server - but in my code it throws the exception.

by the way - on WinXP the same code works flawlessly.

any help would be appreciated.

```
private IpAddress GetAddress(string name)
{
    var result = Dns.BeginGetHostEntry(name,null,null);
    if (!reuslt.AsyncwaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7)))
        return null;
    try
    {
        var addresses = Dns.EndGetHostEntry(result);
        return addresses.AddressList[addresses.AddressList - 1];
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

we have already tried all the functions in Dns like GetHostEntry,GetHostAddresses,GetHostByName,Resolve, etc...

Comment: Why did you need to disable IPV6? its presence should not matter.  You should show your code and confirm the hostname is resolvable via `nslookup`.

Comment: Hey Alex and thanks for responding.
nslookup with given hostname does return us the expected ip address we were looking for.
Our code in C# is added as edit in the original post.